# getting an exception on running simple selenium+java code?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
Invalid port. Exiting...
?????? ??, ???? ??:??:?? ??????? org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'PRAVUDHAS', ip: '192.168.43.15', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at AlertClass.main(AlertClass.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:?????/status] to be available after ????? ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1):

[Download the latest ChromeDriver for your operating system here.](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

- Upgrade ChromeDriver .
- Execute netstat command through CLI to see if you have reached limit of possible open 
  connections or check if there is another application running on the given port.
- Set Driver Path.
- Check your firewall settings, there is a chance that firewall configuration may be 
  causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the .exe driver in the same directory of your project.
If you use chrome - download chrome driver.
If you use firefox - download firefox driver.
etc.